# How to display multiple objects from fields in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am a bit stumped as to how I can add multiple access_token and items_ids in Django Admin. The models and apps involved are as follows. This is my first post so please forgive if it isn't in proper format.

Trans/models.py

class Exchange(models.Model):

```
created = models.DateTimeField()
owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='token', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
access_token = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, default='')
item_id = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, default='')
request_id = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, default='')

class Meta:
    ordering = ('item_id',)
```

I have setup a userprofile section for the admin:

Users/models.py

class UserProfile(models.Model):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True, verbose_name='user', related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
avatar_url = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
dob = models.DateField(verbose_name="dob", blank=True, null=True)
public_token = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='public_token')
access_token = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='access_token')
item_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='item_ID')
just_signed_up = models.BooleanField(default=True)    

def __str__(self):
    return force_text(self.user)

class Meta():
    db_table = 'user_profile'
```

users/forms.py

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('user', 'public_token', 'access_token', 'item_id',)
```

users/admin.py

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

```
search_fields = ('user', 'dob', 'public_token', 'access_token', 'item_id',)
ordering = ('user',)
list_select_related = ('user',)
```

admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)

class UserProfileAdminInline(admin.TabularInline):

```
model = UserProfile
```

I'm really just stumped as I tried making many to many field but couldnt seem to link correctly and or the process broke when testing in a sandbox environment.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  In my case I need to record multiple access_tokens and item_ids for each user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little bit confusing what you are asking...particularly the way that your data model is setup....but I'm going to make a couple of assumptions in my answer (it would be helpful to better understand what you are trying to do at a high level).

I *think* what you are wanting to do is to be able to configure multiple `Exchange` objects per user profile...in which case I would set things up this way:
1. The `related_name` field on the FK to the user profile in the exchange model will be how you access multiple exchanges...so in this case you probably want a pluralized name.
2. To be able to edit multiple in the Django Admin you will need to setup an InlineAdmin object.
3. The CharFields that are actually ON the `UserProfile` will only ever be single fields...if you want multiple then you need to move them to another related object (like the `Exchange` model).
4. I don't think what you want here is a `ManyToMany` as that would imply user's would be sharing these tokens and item ids (or Exchanges?)...but maybe that is what you want...in which case you should change the `ForeignKey` to `UserProfile` from the `Exchange` model to a `ManyToManyField`. The rest of this post assumes you don't want that.

trans/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Exchange(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('item_id', )

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='exchanges', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    access_token = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    item_id = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    request_id = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
```

users/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class UserProfile(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_profile'

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True, verbose_name='user', related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
    avatar_url = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(verbose_name="dob", blank=True, null=True)
    public_token = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    access_token = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    item_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    just_signed_up = models.BooleanField(default=True)    

    def __str__(self):
        return force_text(self.user)
```

users/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from trans.models import Exchange
from users.models import UserProfile


class ExchangeAdminInline(admin.TabularInline):

    model = Exchange


class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = (ExchangeAdminInline, )
    search_fields = ('user', 'dob', 'public_token', 'access_token', 'item_id', )
    ordering = ('user', )
    list_select_related = ('user', )


admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

There is a lot that you can do to configure the inlines to behave how you want...but that's the basics.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comment.  Your first assumption was correct, sorry I am awful at explaining things.  Each exchange instance is for a single user and users will have multiple access_tokens and items_ids in order to represent different accounts.  This was super helpful and I really appreciate it my friend!

Comment: @DavidBednarczyk if the answer provided solved your problem then please mark this question as the correct solution and upvote the answer.